# I'm getting django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed in cmd

Tags: json, django, sqlite

I copied a json file from online. I'm using it for django project.
I entered the following lines in cmd -

```
>>> import json
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> with open('posts.json') as f:
...   posts_json=json.load(f)
...
>>> for post in posts_json:
...   post = Post(title=post['title'], content=post['content'], author_id=post['
user_id'])
...   post.save()
...
```

And the error I got was -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\models\base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields
, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\models\base.py", line 924, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1391, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._e
xecute)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\my_projects-I2onQxk3\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

This is my models.py file -

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField()
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

This is the json file I copied from online https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/master/Django_Blog/snippets/posts.json

Comment: Are you sure there exists a user with the `id` that you pass as `author_id`?

Comment: You don't need to tag your coding editor unless your question is specifically about the editor itself.

Comment: @MattDMo Are u saying about the tag sqlite?

Comment: @Gagankaranth no, about Sublime Text. Your question doesn't have anything to do with Sublime itself, so you don't need to tag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only foreign key here is `author`, so a foreign key constraint failing must mean that there's no user with an id corresponding to the `user_id` field in a record in that data.

Since by a quick glance it looks like there's only user ids 1 and 2, make sure you have those two users in your database, then try again.

Comment: So, what to do here? Should we remove author?

Answer (score 1):

This is a later reply but maybe it will help someone else in the future.

I had the same issue now and the same code and `posts.json` as well, it seems that in `posts.json` the `user_id` it either 1 or 2 so the error means that there is no user with id 1 or 2 in your database.

I would say that there is no user with `id = 2` I supposed you have created a superuser which is `id = 1` and if you create a second user it may not take `id = 2`, so you need to find out what is that id and change it in your `posts.json` file.

That's how I just fixed my problem.

Sorry for my English.